# Create random playlist of albums not recently played?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

Is there a way to create a smart playlist that consists of random albums and when I sync my iPod touch, will remove the music I just heard and replace it with new randomly chosen albums?

If not, is there anything close?  I'd like to play music in album order, hear complete albums and hear music I have not heard recently.

I'm on Windows, so Mac plugins wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

[image: Smart playlist]

Comment: That looks like it should work.  I'll test and come back.  Last time I tried something like that, it chose songs rather than albums.  Has something changed or am I misremembering?

Comment: last played is not in the last _ days should probably be a longer period.  What does 'date added' add to the mix?

Comment: When you typed `Album` my mind thought `Song`, sorry. I haven't purchased an Album in a long time. So this might not work for you. You could try changing "by random" to "by album" and see what that does. I don't have a way to test that since I don't any albums. I post example values (0 days, 25 items). You should play with those values to achieve your desired affect.